# Glassfish Configuration in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

[image: glassfish configuration]  what must i write inside Target inbox

Thanks all interest

Answer (score 4):

This field is optional. You can specify a target server, the default is your local instance.

From the NetBeans help:

> Target: (Optional) Enter a value that is used to identify a cluster
>   and/or stand-alone instance. This value will be used as the value for
>   the target option when running server administration tasks from the
>   IDE. For example, if you have a cluster identified as cluster1 and
>   enter cluster1 as the Target value, when you deploy an application
>   from the IDE to the server the application will be deployed to every
>   instance in the cluster (asadmin deploy --target cluster1 --name myapp
>   myapp.war). When no Target value is specified (default) all commands
>   will be applied to the domain administration server instance.

Comment: why when i deploy my application in cluster Target **cluster1**, the application is deployed with a name like this **appname_cluster1** is there any way to remove this **cluster1**